# Querying objectify for a single entity by key or id

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Given a key or an id, I want to query objectify for a single entity. How might I do that? I am using the following method which I find cumbersome. Is there a one-liner alternative? Here is my method so far:

```
public static Dog getDog(String id) {
         log.info(TAG+": getDog");     
    Key<Dog> key = Key.create(Dog.class, id);
         Map<Key<Dog>, Dog> result = OfyService.ofy().load().keys(key);
         return (Dog) result.values().toArray()[0];
     }
```

Comment: Wow, this is literally answered as the first example in the [Objectify documentation](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BasicOperations) and in extend a bit further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your entity has no ancestor, you want:

```
ofy().load().type(Dog.class).id(dogId).now();
```

If you have an existing key:

```
ofy().load().key(dogKey).now();
```

- Note also the `static import` of `ofy`
- You can substitute `now()` for `safe()` if you'd rather catch an exception than check for a null return value.

The docs give a very good overview of [Basic Operations](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BasicOperations).

**edit**

You say your entity *does* have an ancestor, so you need to specify the parent, like this:

```
Dog otherDog; // this is your ancestor
ofy().load().type(Dog.class).parent(otherDog).id(dogId).now();
```

Comment: My entity does have a parent. But the id is a string. So how come it is not sufficient to do `ofy().load().type(Dog.class).id(dogId).now();`? When I do it, the query fails and returns null. I always have to include the parent by creating a key first.

Comment: In that case `type(Dog.class).id(dogId)` will not contain enough information to form a key and you need to specify the ancestor path (which, btw, your original example doesn't do).  I will update my answer accordingly.